# pass modified parent properties to child class

Tags: php, class, inheritance, properties

I created a parent class (A) and modified some of its public and protected properties.

I created a child class (B) that extends A.

I can see the parent properties at B instance after creating it.

Problem is: The inherited properties of B have the default values of A, from before I modified them.

I want B to hold the modified values of the inherited properties.

How?

```
class Dashboard {
   protected $testBusinessesIds = '';

   public function test_bids($a){
      $this->testBusinessesIds = $a;
   }

}

class DashboardDBHelper extends Dashboard{
   protected $withoutTestBids = '';

   public function __construct(){
    if($this->testBusinessesIds != '')
        $this->withoutTestBids = " AND B.`id`";
   }
}
$d = new Dashboard();
$d->test_bids(23);

$dh = new DashboardDBHelper();
print_r($dh->withoutTestBids);
```

I see: '' instead of  'AND B.`id`'

Comment: @ClémentMalet : If he changes the value of `protected $value` in class A. The class B always get the default value of the class A. That's normal. I'm agree, we need some code. Indeed, following your needs one potential solution would be to use `static` keyword.

Comment: Of course, you have **two independent object instances**. They do not share data, regardless of whether they're of the same class or not. A more concrete use case example would be needed to tell you how to best do what you're trying to do in OOP. `static` may or may not be a *bad* solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to put your property as static. Here's an example:

```
class A {
    protected $value = 1;
    protected static $staticValue = 1;

    public function printStatic() {
        self::$staticValue++;
        echo self::$staticValue;
    }

    public function printNonStatic() {
        $this->value++;
        echo $this->value;
    }
}

class B extends A {

    public function printStatic() {
        echo self::$staticValue;
    }

     public function printNonStatic() {
        echo $this->value;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B();

/* Class A */
$a->printStatic(); // 2
$a->printNonStatic(); // 2

/* Class B */
$b->printStatic(); // 2
$b->printNonStatic(); // 1
```

Static variables does not share the same class/object so if you modify the value it will be changed everywhere.

Comment: Static would work, it is not the optimal solution but it will do.

Comment: Sure, It's one of possible solution. The OP should define what is the best way following his need.